# How to set primary key into message by Kafka JDBC Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How the title says, there is a way in order to set the primary key of the record that the Kafka JDBC Source connector read from the database?

This is the config from `connect-file-source.properties`

```
name=jdbc_source_postgres_foobar_01
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?user=postgres&password=root
table.whitelist=author
mode=timestamp+incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
timestamp.column.name=entity_modify_date
validate.non.null=false
topics=migration
topic.prefix=
```

Is there a properties that does what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [Kafka Connect SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html), try to add the following configuration:

```
transforms=createKey,extractInt
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=id
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractInt.field=specialization_id
```